# NoSuchMethodError when using ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am doing ListView Example from this [site](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html). Below is my code,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    private ListView listView;

    String[] values = new String[] { "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listData);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < values.length ; i++ )
        {
            list.add(values[i]);
        }


        final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter ( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list );

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick ( AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id )
            {
                final String item = ( String ) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                view.animate().setDuration(2000).alpha(0)
                .withEndAction( new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        list.remove(item);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        view.setAlpha(1);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
    {
        HashMap<String,Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

        public MyAdapter( Context context, int id, List<String> list )
        {
            super ( context, id, list );

            for ( int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++ )
            {
                hashMap.put( list.get(i), i );
            }
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId( int position )
        {
            String item = getItem(position);
            return Long.valueOf(hashMap.get(item));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run this code and click on the listview it thorws an error. Following is my logcat.

```
11-29 16:24:49.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21837): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-29 16:24:49.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21837): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator.withEndAction
11-29 16:24:49.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21837):    at com.example.listviewexample.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:52)
11-29 16:24:49.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21837):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
11-29 16:24:49.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21837):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1394)
11-29 16:24:49.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21837):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3024)
11-29 16:24:49.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21837):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3830)
11-29 16:24:49.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21837):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-29 16:24:49.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21837):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-29 16:24:49.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21837):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-29 16:24:49.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21837):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
11-29 16:24:49.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21837):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-29 16:24:49.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21837):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-29 16:24:49.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21837):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
11-29 16:24:49.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21837):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
11-29 16:24:49.249: E/AndroidRuntime(21837):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How to solve this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public ViewPropertyAnimator withEndAction (Runnable runnable)
```

This method **is available only from API 16** so if your device has API < 16 it won't work, unfortunetly. Look at [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html#withStartAction%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

You need to make sure that this method will be executed **only if API > 16**:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
   // use method
}
else {
   // you can't use that method
}
```

Comment: Got it, My application has 4.4 version but my device has 4.0.3 so it is not running in device.

Comment: @Vigbyor This is problem, API 16 is Android 4.1 but 4.0.3 < API 16. Exactly it's API 15 Ice cream sandwich.

Comment: Hmm ok, I will try it in my Nexus 5, It has 4.4

Comment: ok fine, Thanks for your answer, I will accept it in 5 minutes. :)